# Spring-Data FETCH JOIN with Paging is not working

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to use HQL fetching my entity along with sub-entities using JOIN FETCH, this is working fine if I want all the results but it is not the case if I want a Page

My entity is

```
@Entity
@Data
public class VisitEntity {

    @Id
    @Audited
    private long id;

    .
    .
    .   

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,)
    private List<VisitCommentEntity> comments;
}
```

and because I have millions of visits I need to use Pageable and I want to Fetch the comments in a single database query like :

```
@Query("SELECT v FROM VisitEntity v LEFT JOIN FETCH v.comments WHERE v.venue.id = :venueId and ..." )
public Page<VisitEntity> getVenueVisits(@Param("venueId") long venueId,...,
        Pageable pageable);
```

That HQL call throws the following exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.QueryException: query specified join fetching, but the owner of the fetched association was not present in the select list [FromElement{explicit,not a collection join,fetch join,fetch non-lazy properties,classAlias=null,role=com.ro.lib.visit.entity.VisitEntity.comments,tableName=visitdb.visit_comment,tableAlias=comments1_,origin=visitdb.visit visitentit0_,columns={visitentit0_.visit_id ,className=com.ro.lib.visit.entity.VisitCommentEntity}}] [select count(v) FROM com.ro.lib.visit.entity.VisitEntity v LEFT JOIN FETCH v.comments WHERE v.venue.id = :venueId and (v.actualArrival > :date or v.arrival > :date)]
at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1374)
at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1310)
at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.createQuery(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:309)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
```

and once I remove the paging everything works fine

```
@Query("SELECT v FROM VisitEntity v LEFT JOIN FETCH v.comments WHERE v.venue.id = :venueId and  ..." )
public List<VisitEntity> getVenueVisits(@Param("venueId") long venueId,...);
```

Obviously the problem is the count query from Spring-Data, but how can we fix it?

Answer (score 70, accepted):

The easiest way is to use the `countQuery` attribute of the the `@Query` annotation to provide a custom query to be used.

```
@Query(value = "SELECT v FROM VisitEntity v LEFT JOIN FETCH v.comments …",
       countQuery = "select count(v) from VisitEntity v where …")
List<VisitEntity> getVenueVisits(@Param("venueId") long venueId, …);
```

Comment: ehh great but second line , `countQuery = "select count(v) from VisitEntity v where …")`

Comment: Thanks, that's fixed! :)

Comment: temporary:  Oliver could u plz confirm this??  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21203875/difference-between-save-and-saveandflush-in-spring-data-jpa/21204100?noredirect=1#comment38102356_21204100

Comment: If you copied actual query and posted as `countQuery`, do not forget to remove `FETCH`. there should be no `FETCH` in the `countQuery`.

Comment: May be useful to highlight that amount of rows of countQuery corresponds to amount of pages.

Comment: But that leads to warning: `HHH000104: firstResult/maxResults specified with collection fetch; applying in memory` when using pagination..

Comment: @Ruslan did you find any solution for this problem wiht spring data  because hibernate with fetch join make pagination in memory not in database .

Comment: @hichamabdedaime there is one of the best explanation for such problem https://stackoverflow.com/a/46195656/5108737

Comment: @Ruslan thanks for your comment , I already saw this reponse  but my problem related to spring data with specificatoin  to make dynamic search .

Comment: @hichamabdedaime looks like there is no solution in spring data. Take a look to my related question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59935631/avoiding-hhh000104-firstresult-maxresults-specified-with-collection-fetch-app

Comment: Does exist any way to do the countQuery be mans of JpaSpecificationExecutor without Pagable?

Answer (score 15):

Alternatively in newest versions of Spring (supporting JPA 2.1 specification) you can use entity graph like this:

```
@EntityGraph(attributePaths = "roles")
@Query("FROM User user")
Page<User> findAllWithRoles(Pageable pageable);
```

Of course named entity graphs work as well.

Comment: I read more about >> https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-named-entity-graphs. Definitely best solution for 2.1+

Answer (score 6):

You have to specify `countQuery` param for `@Query` and now you can use `Page` or `List` as return value.

```
@Query(value = "SELECT v FROM VisitEntity v LEFT JOIN FETCH v.comments WHERE v.venue.id = :venueId and ...",
       countQuery = "SELECT count(v) FROM VisitEntity v LEFT JOIN v.comments WHERE v.venue.id = :venueId and ..." )
public Page<VisitEntity> getVenueVisits(@Param("venueId") long venueId,...,
        Pageable pageable);
```

Comment: Do you have to fetch the children (e.g. `v.comments`) for the `countQuery`? Or would the following suffice `"SELECT count(v) FROM VisitEntity v  WHERE v.venue.id = :venueId and ..."`?

Comment: Right, for countQuery, no need to specify fetch.

Answer (score 4):

If you want completely control your query build by `Specification` with join fetch you can check `CriteriaQuery` return type and change join fetch logic according to query type like this:

```
public class ContactSpecification implements Specification<Contact> {
    @Override
    public Predicate toPredicate(Root<Contact> root, CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder cb) {
        if(query.getResultType() == Long.class) {
            root.join(Contact_.company);
        } else {
            root.fetch(Contact_.company);
        }
        return cb.equal(root.get(Contact_.company).get(Company_.name), "Company 123");
    }
}
```

I was not able to find this info in documentation, but from `SimpleJpaRepository.getCountQuery()` method you can see query for count request first build for Long return type, and later fetch for expected class is running.

```
CriteriaBuilder builder = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Long> query = builder.createQuery(Long.class);

Root<S> root = applySpecificationToCriteria(spec, domainClass, query);
```

It can be not reliable since it is an implementation details which can be changed, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

Try `countProjection`

```
@Query(value="SELECT v FROM VisitEntity v LEFT JOIN FETCH v.comments WHERE v.venue.id = :venueId and ..." ,
countProjection = "v.id")
public Page<VisitEntity> getVenueVisits(@Param("venueId") long venueId,...,
    Pageable pageable);
```