# Spring Data JPA: How not to repeat myself in countQueries?

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data

I am using Spring Data JPA repositories (1.7.2) and I am typically facing the following scenario:

- entities have lazy-loaded collections
- those collections are *sometimes* eagerly fetched (via JPAQL `fetch join`)
- repositories often return `Page<Foo>` instead of `List<Foo>`

I need to provide `countQuery` to every `@Query` that uses fetch joins on a repository that returns a `Page`. This issue has been discussed in [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21549480/spring-data-fetch-join-with-paging-is-not-working)

My typical repository method looks like this:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT e FROM Employee e LEFT JOIN FETCH e.addresses a " +
    "WHERE e.company.id = :companyId " +
    "AND e.deleted = false " +
    "AND e.primaryAddress.deleted = false " +
    "ORDER BY e.id, a.id",
    countQuery="SELECT count(e) FROM Employee e WHERE e.companyId = :companyId AND e.deleted = false AND e.primaryAddress.deleted = false"
)
Page<Employee> findAllEmployeesWithAddressesForCompany(@Param("companyId") long companyId, Pageable pageable);
```

Obviously, **it's not very DRY**. You can tell that I am repeating all of the conditions in both `value` and `countQuery` parameters. How do I stay DRY here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do something like this

```
public interface MyRepository extends JpaRepository {

    public static final String WHERE_PART = "e.companyId = :companyId AND e.deleted = false AND e.primaryAddress.deleted = false ";

    @Query(value = "SELECT e FROM Employee e LEFT JOIN FETCH e.addresses a " +
        "WHERE " + MyRepository.WHERE_PART
        "ORDER BY e.id, a.id",
        countQuery="SELECT count(e) FROM Employee e WHERE " + MyRepository.WHERE_PART
    )
    Page<Employee> findAllEmployeesWithAddressesForCompany(@Param("companyId") long companyId, Pageable pageable);
```

Comment: Yea that's certainly more DRY.  Now I have to do a tough choice whether I sacrifice some DRY principles or readability (string concatenation + inability of IDE to control syntax of JPAQL statement properly)

Comment: Actually, the [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/Query.html#countQuery--) says this: `Defines a special count query that shall be used for pagination queries to lookup the total number of elements for a page. If non is configured we will derive the count query from the method name.`. So, if the conditions are the same as in the basic query, probably your best option is to let spring-data derive the count query itself. You should check the generated SQL, though, just to be sure.

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't seem to work with fetch joins, check out the linked SO question link in my original post.