# Spring Data JPA repository with specification, pagination and criteria fetch-join

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I am implementing search/filtering service for list of entities, using Spring Data JPA repository with specifications and pagination features. I am trying to reduce number of queries (n+1 problem) and fetch nested data using criteria fetch mechanism.

I have two entity classes:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "delegations")
public class Delegation {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    private Customer customer;

    // more fields, getters, setters, business logic...

}
```

and

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "customers")
public class Customer {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    // more fields, getters, setters, business logic...
}
```

DTO filter class:

```
public class DelegationFilter {

    private String customerName;

    // more filters, getters, setters...
}
```

And search / filtering service:

```
public class DelegationService {
    public Page<Delegation> findAll(DelegationFilter filter, Pageable page) {
        Specifications<Delegation> spec = Specifications.where(
                customerLike(filter.getCustomerName())
        );
        return delegationRepository.findAll(spec, page);
    }

    public List<Delegation> findAll(DelegationFilter filter) {
        Specifications<Delegation> spec = Specifications.where(
                customerLike(filter.getCustomerName())
        );
        return delegationRepository.findAll(spec);
    }

    private Specification<Delegation> customerLike(String customerName) {
        return (root, query, cb) -> {
            Join<Delegation,Customer> join = (Join) root.fetch(Delegation_.customer);
            return cb.like(cb.lower(join.get(Customer_.name)), addWildCards(customerName.toLowerCase()));
        };
    }

    private static String addWildCards(String param) {
        return '%' + param + '%';
    }
}
```

**Problem**:

When I call `findAll(DelegationFilter filter, Pageable page)` I am getting exception:

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: 
org.hibernate.QueryException: query specified join fetching, but the owner 
of the fetched association was not present in the select list
```

Is there a way to solve this problem?

`findAll(DelegationFilter filter)` (method without pagination) works like charm... Using `join` only (without `fetch`) also works fine (even with pagination)

I know that there is solution for JPQL:
[Spring-Data FETCH JOIN with Paging is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21549480/spring-data-fetch-join-with-paging-is-not-working)
But I want to stick with criteria api...

I am using Spring Boot 1.4 (spring 4.3.2, spring-data-jpa 1.10.2) and Hibernate 5.0.9

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I was facing the same problem, and I found a workaround ([source](https://coderanch.com/t/656073/framework/Spring-Data-fetch-join-Specification)).

You can check the query's return type at runtime, so that if it is `Long` (the type the count query returns) you join and otherwise you fetch. In your code it will look like this:

```
...
private Specification<Delegation> customerLike(String customerName) {
    return (root, query, cb) -> {
        if (query.getResultType() != Long.class && query.getResultType() != long.class) {
          Join<Delegation,Customer> join = (Join) root.fetch(Delegation_.customer);
        } else {
          Join<Delegation,Customer> join = root.join(Delegation_.customer);
        }
        return cb.like(cb.lower(join.get(Customer_.name)), addWildCards(customerName.toLowerCase()));
    };
}
...
```

I know it's not very clean, but it's the only solution I've ofund ATM.

Comment: Looks ugly :) But seems like solution... Thanks :)

Comment: I cannot believe this is not a more commonly referenced solution, I looked for ages. All other solutions I came across required a separate Count Query / JPQL, never with a custom specification. +100 thank you so much

Comment: Interesting is there any updates about that in the new versions of Spring Data?