# Spring Data 3 FETCH JOIN with Paging and Specifications is not working properly it is paging in memory

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I am using spring boot 3 with Jpa Specifications for build a dynamic query, Paging and Fetch Join together in order to avoid N+1 query problem. **But pagination is applied at application level in memory and not a database level with query as it should be.**

My User entity is

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User implements UserDetails, Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.UUID)
    private UUID id;
    
    @Column(name = "names")
    private String names;
    
    
    @ManyToMany(cascade = {
            CascadeType.PERSIST,
            CascadeType.MERGE
    })
    @JoinTable(name = "users_roles",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id"))
    private Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<>();

...
}
```

My User repository is

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends 
        JpaRepository<User, UUID>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<User> { ... }
```

My UserGateway uses UserRepository.findAll(Specification<T> spec, Pageable pageable)

```
@Repository
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class UserGatewayImpl implements UserGateway {


    private final UserRepository userRepository;


    @Override
    public Page<User> findByParams(UserSearchCommand searchCriteria, Pageable pageable) {

        var userSpecification = buildCriteria(searchCriteria);

        return userRepository.findAll(userSpecification, pageable);
    }
}
```

My build criteria. In order to avoid "org.hibernate.query.SemanticException: query specified join fetching, but the owner of the fetched association was not present in the select list" exception because JPA executes 2 queries, I check resultType to know if it is the count query. Like in this answer [Fetch join with paging solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39614628/spring-data-jpa-repository-with-specification-pagination-and-criteria-fetch-joi)

```
    private Specification<User> buildCriteria(UserSearchCommand queryCriteria) {

        return (root, criteriaQuery, criteriaBuilder) -> {
            List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();

            if (Long.class != criteriaQuery.getResultType() && 
                    long.class != criteriaQuery.getResultType()) {
                root.fetch("roles", JoinType.LEFT);
            } else {
                root.join("roles", JoinType.LEFT);
            }


            if (nonNull(queryCriteria.getNames())) {
                predicates
                        .add(criteriaBuilder.and(
                                criteriaBuilder.equal(root.get("names"), queryCriteria.getNames())));
            }

            return criteriaBuilder.and(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[0]));
        };
    }
```

That seems to work. The pagination "works". But when we take a look at the console and check the query generated by hibernate I see that the pagination is not being applied at the database level in query. Pagination is applied at application level in memory.

Generated query is

```
...
    from
        users u1_0 
    left join
        (users_roles r1_0 
    join
        roles r1_1 
            on r1_1.id=r1_0.role_id) 
                on u1_0.id=r1_0.user_id 
        where
            1=1 
        order by
            u1_0.id desc
```

I want to use JPA specifications, paging and FETCH JOIN together but paging is applied at application level in memory. Paging should be applied at database level in query.

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate can not really do any better in this case, because when a collection is fetch joined, it can't apply the SQL limit/offset clauses, because the SQL cardinality does not match the entity result cardinality.

You can try using Blaze-Persistence on top, which also comes with a [Spring Data integration](https://persistence.blazebit.com/documentation/1.6/entity-view/manual/en_US/#spring-data-integration), that automatically transforms queries to a form which allows efficient pagination. Give it a try. After the initial setup, you only need to replace `@EnableJpaRepositories` with `@EnableBlazeRepositories`.

Comment: Many thanks Christian. I will try what you recommend.