# Using Spring data JPA EntityGraph with LAZY load mode for NamedAttributeNode field

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, out-of-memory, lazy-loading

I am facing with 2 problems: N + 1 query and Out Of Memory (OOM).

I solved OOM by paging and lazy loading:

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "department_id")
private Set<Employee> employees;
```

But when I use lazy loading, N + 1 query happened. So I try to use `EntityGraph` as https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-named-entity-graphs. But as my researches and local test, `EntityGraph` always do eager loading for `NamedAttributeNode` field - association field, which I want to be lazy loading - do not load all data at first:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "department")
@NamedEntityGraph(name = "Department",
        attributeNodes = {
                @NamedAttributeNode("employees")
        }
)
public class Department implements Serializable {
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "department_id")
    private Set<Employee> employees;
}
```

So are there any way to get them both ? Use `EntityGraph` to avoid N + 1 and lazy loading to avoid OOM ?

UPDATE:
Can `EntityGraph` works fine with Pageable effectively ? I mean do not load all data in JOIN query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `EntityGraph` all your `NamedAttributeNode` associations will be loaded in 1 query with `Join` clause. Enable sql log to see how many queries hibernate does for loading entities in different scenarios

```
logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG
```

You will see that using `@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)` without `EntityGraph` it loads employees in separate `select` queries (N + 1), but using `EntityGraph` it performs only 1 `select ... join`

Also don't forget to specify entity graph name in repository like:

```
@EntityGraph(value = "Department")
List<Department> findAll();
```

**UPDATE:** Spring DATA Pagination doesn't work on database side. It will fetch all data and then filtered in memory. That's how it works.. There are some workarounds, check this links:

[How can I avoid the Warning "firstResult/maxResults specified with collection fetch; applying in memory!" when using Hibernate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11431670/how-can-i-avoid-the-warning-firstresult-maxresults-specified-with-collection-fe/46195656#46195656)

[Avoiding "HHH000104: firstResult/maxResults specified with collection fetch; applying in memory!" using Spring Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59935631/avoiding-hhh000104-firstresult-maxresults-specified-with-collection-fetch-app)

[VladMihalcea Blog The best way to fix the Hibernate HHH000104](https://vladmihalcea.com/fix-hibernate-hhh000104-entity-fetch-pagination-warning-message/)

As for me the solution could be creating custom repository and using `EntityManager` to construct query manually.

Comment: "You will see that using @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER) without EntityGraph it loads employees in separate select queries (N + 1), but using EntityGraph it performs only 1 select ... join" -> this is what I mentioned above: it will load Employees EAGERLY but I want it to be LAZY

Comment: @ThachHuynh Ok, then why do you need `EntityGraph`?  Just don't use `@NamedAttributeNode` for lazy employees. In that case employees will not be loaded at all.

Comment: I use EntityGraph because it can avoid N + 1 select problem.

Comment: Are there any other ways ?

Comment: @ThachHuynh so you mean you want to load employees but limit the number of it according to the pagination?

Comment: Yes. Pagination or lazy load is ok.

Comment: But I'm not sure that spring data jpa pagination is real pagination. I mean it must not load all data to memory and do paging on it. It must come to db and execute query every batch.

Comment: @ThachHuynh I've updated answer. Probably you could find smth useful there

Comment: "I'm not sure that spring data jpa pagination is real pagination" -> This is not true. Spring Data JPA _will_ apply the pagination at the database level.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution is:

- Fetch first your records with pagination but without `@EntityGraph`.
- Fetch your records with `@EntityGraph` from previous returned ids.

=> No N+1 complexity, only 2 SQL requests and no native queries, etc.

Example:

On your main repository, add `@EntityGraph` annotation with associations you want to fetch:

```java
public interface CarRepository extends JpaRepository<Car, String>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<Car>, CarCustomRepository {

    @Override
    @EntityGraph(attributePaths = { "foo", "bar", "bar.baz" })
    List<Car> findAllById(Iterable<String> ids);

}
```

Create a custom repository with a `findAllWithEntityGraph` method:

```java
public interface CarCustomRepository {

    Page<Car> findAllWithEntityGraph(Specification<Car> specification, Pageable pageable);

}
```

The implementation of the custom repository. It first fetch entities without entity graph, then it re-fetch them with entity graph in order to load associations. Don't forget to re-sort entities in to preserve order:

```java
public class CarCustomRepositoryImpl implements CarCustomRepository {

    @Autowired
    @Lazy
    private CarRepository carRepository;

    @Override
    public Page<Car> findAllWithEntityGraph(Specification<Car> specification, Pageable pageable) {
        Page<Car> page = carRepository.findAll(specification, pageable);
        List<String> ids = page.getContent().stream().map(Car::getId).collect(Collectors.toList());
        List<Car> cars = carRepository.findAllById(ids).stream()
                .sorted(Comparator.comparing(car -> ids.indexOf(car.getId())))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        return new PageImpl<>(cars, pageable, page.getTotalElements());
    }

}
```

Then, you just have to invoke `CarRepository#findAllWithEntityGraph` method in order to fetch records **with** pagination and **no** N+1 complexity.

The question is: why hibernate does not have this behavior by default?

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution would be to fetch the entities and then initialize the needed `joins`.

```
Page<Department> depPages = this.repository.findAll(PageRequest.of(page, maxRows, sort));
for (Department d : depPages.getContent()) Hibernate.initialize(d.getEmployees());
```

**Important:** Must be run inside a transaction, otherwise you will get a `can't initialize` exception.